# DynamoDB - how to query by something that is not the primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

So, I have a table on DybamoDB with this structure:

```
- userId as the primarykey (it's a uuid)
- email
- hashedPassword
```

I want to, as someone is signing up, find out if there's already someone using that email.

This should be easy but, as far as I know, you can't query on DynamoDB unless you are using the primary key as parameters or the sort key (and I'm not sure if it would make sense to make email a sort key).

The other way I found out was using a Global Secondary Index, which is pretty much an index table you create using another field as the primary sort of, but this is billable and since I'm still developing and testing I did not want to have expenses.

Does anyone have another option? Or am I wrong and there's another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like other answers, I also think that **GSI is the best option** here.

But I would like to also add that since search capabilities of DynamoDB are very limited, it is not uncommon to use DynamoDB with something else for that very purpose. One such use case is described in the AWS blog:

- [Indexing Amazon DynamoDB Content with Amazon Elasticsearch Service Using AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/)

> The **main querying capabilities** of DynamoDB are centered around lookups using a **primary key**. However, there are certain times where richer querying capabilities are required. Indexing the content of your DynamoDB tables with a search engine such as Elasticsearch would allow for full-text search.

Obviously, I don't recommend using ES over GSI in your scenario. But it is worth knowing that DynamoDB can be, and is often, used with other services to extend its search capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Even you put `email` as `sort key` alongside of `userId` as `primary key`, you can't query only using email(unless it is `scan` operation). You don't want to use scan to see whether email exists in your table. It's like iterating the each value by scanning the whole table.

I think your best option is `global secondary index`. Another option would be creating a new table which only includes `email` values, but in that case you have to write/maintain to multiple tables which is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about another table, but yeah...not the best option. I guess GSI is the way to go then, even though I was hoping I could avoid paying for anything, but thaank you!!

Comment: One thing I was thinking: the GSI table is just like a regular table but maintaned by DynamoDB or it's more like an Index (such as in a sql database)? If it is a copy of the table but with the partition key being another one, I think I'd rather create another table, as you suggest and prevent me from being charged, since both options (GSI or another table) would mean double the writing units, so at least I'm not paying for something more (at least now, I can change it eventually).

Comment: @user3648701 it could be an option to consider (i suggested as second option since email uniqueness can be critical in most of the domains) -  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html read/write capacity units sections may provide some insights too

Answer (score 1):

> The other way I found out was using a Global Secondary Index, which is pretty much a index table you create using another field as the primary sort of, but this is billable and since I'm still developing and testing I did not want to have expenses.

As @Ersoy has said, GSI is the legit solution, even it will increase the consumed writes units.

Dynamodb is cheap for a low-traffic app and/or a test environment, but to hold these expenses flat, you can:

1. Use [dynamodb local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) during local devs/tests and CI builds
2. Choose a [provisioned capacity mode](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) for your table (you may find its free-tier interesting)

Comment: I did not think about testing locally, to be honest, might be a good idea. But i'm also going to read about the second item. Thank you!!